# Disable password suggestions of Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way of disabling the "Use suggested password" menu in Chrome or the "Use a Securely Generated Password" menu in Firefox directly from the React code?
I'm talking about this one:

[image]

I want this disabled because, first of all by not having a special char it is not meeting my all password format requirements. Second, it is sitting on top of my menu showing what it still needs - to meet all the format requirements.

I've tried with `autoComplete='off'` and `autoComplete='new-password'` but these have no effect on the above mentioned, they have only on the auto filling of the input.

Answer (score -2):

did you add type='password' to your component?

```html
<input type='password'>
```

Comment: type is dynamically set by the user, if he wants or not the password to be visible. How is this related to the question and how is this solving the issue stated above?